# Get returncode of a detached subprocess?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

I'm trying to write a submitter for a job scheduler. As I do not know when the jobs come and how long the jobs will run, I use multiprocessing to spawn one process for each job with subprocess and detach to be able to process the next job. Meanwhile this works pretty good, **but** I'd like to get the returncode after the jobs finished, is that possible? I tried several subprocess variations, but those returning the RC were blocking the process for the runtime of the job.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding=utf-8
import time
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

JobsList = []

def SubmitJob(jobname):
    """ Submit the next requested job """
    print(f"Starting job {jobname}...")
    JobDir ="/home/xxxxx/Jobs/"
    JobMem = "{}{}.sh".format(JobDir, jobname)
    SysoutFile = "./Sysout/{}.out".format(jobname)
    fh = open(SysoutFile, 'w')
    kwargs = {}
    kwargs.update(start_new_session=True)
    p = subprocess.Popen(JobMem, shell = False, stdout = fh, **kwargs)
    pid = p.pid
    print(f"Job {jobname} pid {pid} submitted...")

def PrepareSubmit():
    """ Create and start one process per job """
    jobs = []

    for Job in JobsList:
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=SubmitJob, 
                                          args=(Job,))
        jobs.append(process)
        JobsList.remove(Job)

    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print("All jobs submitted...")

def main():
    """ Check queue for new job requests """
    number_of_lines = 0
    jobs_list = []

    while 1:
        job_queue = open("/home/xxxxx/Development/Python/#Projects/Scheduler/jobs.que", 'r')
        lines = job_queue.readlines()

        if len(lines) > number_of_lines:
            jobs_list.append(lines[len(lines)-1])
            NewJob = lines[len(lines)-1][:-1]
            JobsList.append(NewJob)
            PrepareSubmit()
            number_of_lines = number_of_lines+1

        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

The while loop in main() is for testing purpose only.

Can any someone tell me if that is possible and how? Thanks in advance.

---

This is the code that gives me a return code but doesn't send a job until the previous job is finished. So if I have a long-running job, it delays the process of running jobs, what I called blocking.

```
def Submit(job):
    """ Submit the next requested job """
    print(f"Starting job {job}...")
    JobDir ="/home/uwe/Jobs/"
    JobMem = "{}{}.sh".format(JobDir, job)
    SysoutFile = "./Sysout/{}.out".format(job)
    fh = open(SysoutFile, 'w')
    kwargs = {}
    kwargs.update(start_new_session=True)
    p = subprocess.Popen(JobMem, shell = False, stdout = fh, **kwargs)
    pid = p.pid

    while p.poll() == None:
        a = p.poll()
        print(a)
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        rc = p.returncode
        print(f"PID: {pid} rc: {rc}")

def main(): 
    JobsList = ['JOB90501','JOB00001','JOB00002','JOB00003']

    for Job in JobsList:
        Submit(Job)
```

Roy, this is my current code after your last hint:

```
def SubmitJob(jobname):
    """ Submit the next requested job """
    JobDir ="/home/uwe/Jobs/"
    JobMem = "{}{}.sh".format(JobDir, jobname)
    SysoutFile = "./Sysout/{}.out".format(jobname)
    fh = open(SysoutFile, 'w')
    kwargs = {}
    kwargs.update(start_new_session=True)
    p = subprocess.Popen(JobMem, shell = False, stdout = fh, **kwargs)
    ProcessList[p] = p.pid
    print(f"Started job {jobname} - PID: {p.pid}")

def main(): 
    c_JobsList = ['JOB00001','JOB00002','JOB00003']

    for Job in c_JobsList:
        SubmitJob(Job)

    for p, pid in ProcessList.items():
        RcFile = "./Sysout/{}.rc".format(pid)
        f = open(RcFile, 'w')
        while p.poll() == None:
            a = p.poll()
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            rc = p.returncode
            f.writelines(str(rc))
            print(f"PID: {pid} rc: {rc}")

        f.close()
```

and the output:

```
Started job JOB00001 - PID: 5426
Started job JOB00002 - PID: 5427
Started job JOB00003 - PID: 5429
PID: 5426 rc: 0
PID: 5427 rc: 0
PID: 5429 rc: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit (the original answer below for future reference)

The natuaram means to use for this purpose is `Popen.poll`, but apparently it doesn't work in some cases (see https://lists.gt.net/python/bugs/633489). The solution I'd like to propose is using `Popen.wait` with a very short timeout, as in the following code sample:

```
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sleep", "3"])
print(f"Created process {p.pid}")

count = 0
while True: 
    try:
        ret = p.wait(.001) # wait for 1 ms
        print(f"Got a return code {ret}")
        break
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e: 
        print("..", end = "")

    time.sleep(.5)
    print(f"Still waiting, count is {count}")
    count += 1

print ("Done!")
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Created process 30040
..Still waiting, count is 0
..Still waiting, count is 1
..Still waiting, count is 2
..Still waiting, count is 3
..Still waiting, count is 4
..Still waiting, count is 5
Got a return code 0
Done
```

#### Original idea - Popen.poll

The method you should be using is `Popen.poll` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll)). It returns the exit status of the process, or `None` if it's still running.

To use it, you'll have to keep the 'popen' objects you get when you call `subprocess.Popen`, and later in time `poll` on these objects.

Comment: Roy, thanks for answering. This was one of the variations I had tried. When I poll() after Popen, the process blocks and the next job can only start when the previous one has finished. I'd like to start the next process at once and to get the rc later.

Comment: Emm. Apparently, there's an issue with poll (https://lists.gt.net/python/bugs/633489). I have another solution using wait with a timeout - I'll add the code in a minute.

Comment: @UweB - does this solve the challenge you were facing?

Comment: Roy, this also blocks the subprocess process so that multiprocess can't submit job2 instantly after job1.

Comment: What OS and version of Python are you using?

Comment: And - when you run my code, do you see the output I'm getting?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.6.9. When I'm running your code, the output looks like yours

Comment: If the output you see is identical to mine, it means that neither subprocess.Popen not wait with a timeout block your process.There's something I'm not sure I get about your code, though. You seem to be spawning a new process twice for every job.
once when you call multiprocessing.Process and another when you call popen. There's no need to call both of them.

Comment: Roy, you're right, I was obviously thinking too complicated. Omitting the multiprocessing part leads to the same results. Thanks for pointing that out. But I still have the problem that when I start a job with subprocess, the next job can only be started when the previous one has finished - when I poll() or wait() for the return code. Without poll() or wait() all jobs start immediately, but I do not get any return code. I'm going in circles.

Comment: Would you like to post the updated code somewhere, so I can have a look?

Comment: This is the code that submits all requested jobs at once, but gets no return code: 
`import subprocess, time

def Submit(job):
 JobDir ="/home/uwe/Jobs/"
 JobMem = "{}{}.sh".format(JobDir, job)
 SysoutFile = "./Sysout/{}.out".format(job)
 RcFile = "./Sysout/{}.rc".format(job)
 fh = open(SysoutFile, 'w')
 kwargs = {}
 kwargs.update(start_new_session=True)
 p = subprocess.Popen(JobMem, shell = False, stdout = fh, **kwargs)
 pid = p.pid
 print(f"Job {job} pid {pid} ended...")

def main(): 
 Jobs = ['job list]
 
 for Job in Jobs:
  Submit(Job)`

Comment: Formatting - don't worry about it. The code seems fine to me. How do you know it's blocked when trying to submit a job?

Comment: I added the alternative code as an answer for better formatting

Comment: It's better to add the alternative code to the original question (you can edit it). But I see your issue. you should do the polling on all the processes outside of submit. Would you like me to show what it would look like?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've changed that. As I'm out for the rest of the day, I'll try your tip tomorrow and show the result. Have a nice day!

Comment: I added my current code to my question. Roy, thanks for your support!